# Difference between driver.quit() and driver.close() in selenium

Tags: selenium

Could you please share your thoughts on the difference between driver.quit() and driver.close()?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Close: closes the browser window without ending the session or killing the driver instance but Quite kills your session and the driver instance and of course closes the browser window.

Comment: Thanks for the update